# How do I add data from other models to a view in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Scenario:
A question is generated in a previous view page by the user. For example: "Question 1". This inputted question needs to appear on a future create page so the respondent can see it. The answers follow it.

I am unsure how to link this up. How do I get data from the "question" table to appear on the "respondent" create page?

I have aimed to set up relationships between the Respondents and Questions classes as well as edit the controllers and view/create pages.

Respondent Model:

```php
public function questions()
{
    return this->hasMany('App\questions');
}
```

Question Model:

```php
public function responses()
{
    return this->hasMany('App\respondents');
}
```

QuestionsController:

```php
public function index()
{
    $question = questions::all();
    $questionnaire = questionnaires::all();
    return view('question.index', compact('question', $question, 'questionnaire', $questionnaire));
}
```

RespondentsController:

```php
public function index()
{
    $question = questions::all();
    $respondent= respondents::all();
    return view('respondent.index', compact('question', $question, 'respondent', $respondent));
}
```

Respondent Create Page:

```php
<div class="form-group">
    @foreach($question as $insert)
        <label for="title">{{$insert->question1}}</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="response1" value="1">Agree</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="response1" value="2">Disagree</label>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Currently, I am getting the error: "Undefined variable: question".

In hindsight, the question should appear above the two radio buttons.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you add the code for the RespondentsController `create` action to your question

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this.. because compact behind the scenes passes the variable which it takes as string

```
public function index()
    {
      $question = questions::all();
      $respondent= respondents::all();
      return view('respondent.index',compact('question', 'respondent'));
    }
```

Or you can do like this.

```
public function index()
    {
      $question = questions::all();
      $respondent= respondents::all();
      return view('respondent.index')->with(['question' => $question, 'respondent'=> $respondent]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but the error is still there: "undefined variable: question"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
return view('respondent.index',compact('question', $question, 'respondent', $respondent));
```

the second parameter of `view()` is an array.

Either use:

```
return view('respondent.index',compact('question', 'respondent'));
```

compact create an array from passed variables

or

```
return view('respondent.index',['question' => $question, 'respondent' => $respondent]);
```

Comment: Thank you, but the error is still there: "undefined variable: question"